# Octave precision fluctuates

Tags: octave

According to Octave's documentation for [`format`](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.2/Terminal-Output.html), the default for `short` is:

```
By default, Octave displays 5 significant digits in a human
readable form (option ‘short’ paired with ‘loose’ format for
matrices). If format is invoked without any options, this default
format is restored. 

short

    Fixed point format with 5 significant figures in a field that
    is a maximum of 10 characters wide. (default).

    If Octave is unable to format a matrix so that columns line up
    on the decimal point and all numbers fit within the maximum
    field width then it switches to an exponential ‘e’ format.

short e long e

    Exponential format. The number to be represented is split
    between a mantissa and an exponent (power of 10). The mantissa
    has 5 significant digits in the short format and 15 digits in
    the long format. For example, with the ‘short e’ format, pi is
    displayed as 3.1416e+00.
```

This is what I get:

```
octave:8> pi*1e3

   ans =  3141.6

octave:9> pi*1e4

   ans =  31415.92654
```

I can see how `short` yields the 1st output, but not how the 2nd output precision is arrived at.  Can anyone please explain?

**Steps taken**

I think I'm already at default conditions other than for 1 statement in my ~/.octaverc: `format compact`. I only use Octave in CLI mode via `octave --no-window-system --silent`. The results of `[a b c]=format` and `ver` are:

```
octave:1> [a b c] = format
a = short
b = compact
error: element number 3 undefined in return list
octave:1> ver
----------------------------------------------------------------------
GNU Octave Version: 5.2.0 (hg id: eb46a9f47164)
GNU Octave License: GNU General Public License
Operating System: CYGWIN_NT-10.0-19041 3.1.7-340.x86_64 2020-08-22 17:48 UTC x86_64
```

Version 5.2 is the latest one from Cygwin.

I get the same results using the GUI (`octave --gui`), both in terms of the fluctuating precision and the outputs of `format` and `ver`.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to recreate your result using Octave 6.2.0.  Are you sure you reset to default conditions before getting the above output? you can call `format` with up to three output variables to verify your current state. E.g.:

```
octave:6> format
octave:7> [a b c] = format
a = short
b = loose
c = lowercase
octave:8> pi*1e3
ans = 3141.6
octave:9> pi*1e4
ans = 3.1416e+04
```

I get the same results in the CLI and the GUI.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions on what to investigate, Nick J.  I added the results to my original question.